# How to "add" or "install" plugins for cyrus-sasl?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, cyrus

I'm working with CentOS 5.5 on a VPS, building a website. All what I want now is just to send mail to users. I decided to do this with postfix and smtp.gmail.com

I had a trouble when setting up Postfix(2.2.3), within the maillog, I found this warning:

```
warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
```

So I installed cyrus-sasl(2.1.22), but later I found that maybe libplain and liblogin modules are needed. But, I cannot find *libplain.so* or *liblogin.so* under */usr/lib/sasl2* directory.

I wonder how to "add" or "install" these two modules (or plugins)? Or how to reconfigure cyrus-sasl? Or, to be stupid, just remove cyrus-sasl (But this causes another problem: as a dependency of cyrus-sasl, yum remove might also delete postfix..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CentOS they're under cyrus-sasl-plain:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain
```